# Override \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Uploader.php

Tags: magento2, preference

I'm working on 2.4.5 upgrade and Magento has a bug in the core. I need to work around the bug by overriding a class.

I created a plugin to override it via preference.

What am I missing?

**/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Uploader" type="CustomVendor\UploaderOverride\Model\Import\Uploader"/>
</config>
```

**/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CustomVendor_UploaderOverride"/>
</config>
```

**/Model/Import/Uploader.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace CustomVendor\UploaderOverride\Model\Import;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\TargetDirectory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverPool;

/**
 * Import entity product model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * phpcs:disable Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
 */
class Uploader extends \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Uploader
{
    /**
     * HTTP scheme
     * used to compare against the filename and select the proper DriverPool adapter
     * @var string
     */
    private $httpScheme = 'http://';

    /**
     * Temp directory.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_tmpDir = '';

    /**
     * Destination directory.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_destDir = '';

    /**
     * All mime types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_allowedMimeTypes = [
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png',
    ];

    public const DEFAULT_FILE_TYPE = 'application/octet-stream';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
     */
    protected $_imageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension
     */
    protected $_validator;

    /**
     * Instance of filesystem directory write interface.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $_directory;

    /**
     * Instance of filesystem read factory.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory
     */
    protected $_readFactory;

    /**
     * Instance of media file storage database.
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $_coreFileStorageDb;

    /**
     * Instance of media file storage.
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage
     */
    protected $_coreFileStorage;

    /**
     * Instance of random data generator.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Math\Random
     */
    private $random;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $fileSystem;

    /**
     * Directory and filename must be no more than 255 characters in length
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $maxFilenameLength = 255;

    /**
     * @var TargetDirectory
     */
    private $targetDirectory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDb
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage $coreFileStorage
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension $validator
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Filesystem\File\ReadFactory $readFactory
     * @param string|null $filePath
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random|null $random
     * @param TargetDirectory|null $targetDirectory
     * @throws FileSystemException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDb,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage $coreFileStorage,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension $validator,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Filesystem\File\ReadFactory $readFactory,
        $filePath = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $random = null,
        TargetDirectory $targetDirectory = null
    ) {
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->_coreFileStorageDb = $coreFileStorageDb;
        $this->_coreFileStorage = $coreFileStorage;
        $this->_validator = $validator;
        $this->fileSystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT);
        $this->_readFactory = $readFactory;
        if ($filePath !== null) {
            $this->_setUploadFile($filePath);
        }
        $this->random = $random ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Math\Random::class);
        $this->targetDirectory = $targetDirectory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(TargetDirectory::class);
    }

    /**
     * Initiate uploader default settings
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $this->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $this->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $this->setAllowedExtensions(array_keys($this->_allowedMimeTypes));
        $imageAdapter = $this->_imageFactory->create();
        $this->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
        $this->_uploadType = self::SINGLE_STYLE;
    }

    /**
     * Proceed moving a file from TMP to destination folder
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param bool $renameFileOff
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function move($fileName, $renameFileOff = false)
    {
        $this->setAllowRenameFiles(!$renameFileOff);

        if ($fileName && preg_match('/\bhttps?:\/\//i', $fileName, $matches)) {
            $url = str_replace($matches[0], '', $fileName);
            $driver = ($matches[0] === $this->httpScheme) ? DriverPool::HTTP : DriverPool::HTTPS;
            $tmpFilePath = $this->downloadFileFromUrl($url, $driver);
        } else {
            $tmpFilePath = $this->_directory->getRelativePath($this->getTempFilePath($fileName));
        }

        $this->_setUploadFile($tmpFilePath);
        $rootDirectory = $this->getTargetDirectory()->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
        $destDir = $rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->getDestDir());
        $result = $this->save($destDir);

        if (\is_array($result)) {
            unset($result['path']);
            $result['name'] = self::getCorrectFileName($result['name']);

            // Directory and filename must be no more than 255 characters in length
            if (strlen($result['file'] ?? '') > $this->maxFilenameLength) {
                throw new \LengthException(
                    __('Filename is too long; must be %1 characters or less', $this->maxFilenameLength)
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Writes a url-based file to the temp directory.
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $driver
     * @return string
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function downloadFileFromUrl($url, $driver)
    {
        $parsedUrlPath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

        if (!$parsedUrlPath) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Could not parse resource url.'));
        }
        $urlPathValues = explode('/', $parsedUrlPath);
        $fileName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\._-]+/i', '', end($urlPathValues));
        //phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($fileExtension && !$this->checkAllowedExtension($fileExtension)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Disallowed file type.'));
        }
        $tmpFileName = str_replace(".$fileExtension", '', $fileName);
        $tmpFileName .= '_' . $this->random->getRandomString(16);
        $tmpFileName .= $fileExtension ? ".$fileExtension" : '';
        $tmpFilePath = $this->_directory->getRelativePath($this->getTempFilePath($tmpFileName));

        if (!$this->_directory->isWritable($this->getTmpDir())) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('Import images directory must be writable in order to process remote images.')
            );
        }
        $this->_directory->writeFile(
            $tmpFilePath,
            $this->_readFactory->create($url, $driver)->readAll()
        );

        return $tmpFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare information about the file for moving
     *
     * @param string $filePath
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _setUploadFile($filePath)
    {
        try {
            $fullPath = $this->_directory->getAbsolutePath($filePath);
            if ($this->getTmpDir()) {
                $tmpDir = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryReadByPath(
                    $this->_directory->getAbsolutePath($this->getTmpDir())
                );
            } else {
                $tmpDir = $this->_directory;
            }
            $readable = $tmpDir->isReadable($fullPath);
        } catch (ValidatorException $exception) {
            $readable = false;
        }
        if (!$readable) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('File \'%1\' was not found or has read restriction.', $filePath)
            );
        }
        $this->_file = $this->_readFileInfo($filePath);

        $this->_validateFile();
    }

    /**
     * Reads file info
     *
     * @param string $filePath
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _readFileInfo($filePath)
    {
        $fullFilePath = $this->_directory->getAbsolutePath($filePath);
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($fullFilePath);
        return [
            'name' => $fileInfo['basename'],
            'type' => $this->_getMimeTypeByExt($fileInfo['extension']),
            'tmp_name' => $filePath,
            'error' => 0,
            'size' => $this->_directory->stat($filePath)['size']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validate uploaded file by type and etc.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _validateFile()
    {
        $filePath = $this->_file['tmp_name'];
        if ($this->_directory->isReadable($filePath)) {
            $this->_fileExists = true;
        } else {
            $this->_fileExists = false;
        }

        $fileExtension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!$this->checkAllowedExtension($fileExtension)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Disallowed file type.'));
        }
        //run validate callbacks
        foreach ($this->_validateCallbacks as $params) {
            if (is_object($params['object'])
                && method_exists($params['object'], $params['method'])
                && is_callable([$params['object'], $params['method']])
            ) {
                $params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_directory->getAbsolutePath($filePath));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns file MIME type by extension
     *
     * @param string $ext
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getMimeTypeByExt($ext)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($ext, $this->_allowedMimeTypes)) {
            return $this->_allowedMimeTypes[$ext];
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Obtain TMP file path prefix
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTmpDir()
    {
        return $this->_tmpDir;
    }

    /**
     * Set TMP file path prefix
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    public function setTmpDir($path)
    {
        if (is_string($path) && $this->_directory->isReadable($path)) {
            $this->_tmpDir = $path;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain destination file path prefix
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDestDir()
    {
        return $this->_destDir;
    }

    /**
     * Set destination file path prefix
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    public function setDestDir($path)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/OVERRIDE-IS-WORKING.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('OVERRIDE IS WORKING');

        $directoryRoot = $this->getTargetDirectory()->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT);
        if (is_string($path) && $directoryRoot->isWritable($path)) {
            $this->_destDir = $path;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Move files from TMP folder into destination folder
     *
     * @param string $tmpPath
     * @param string $destPath
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _moveFile($tmpPath, $destPath)
    {
        if ($this->_directory->isFile($tmpPath)) {
            $tmpRealPath = $this->_directory->getDriver()->getRealPath(
                $this->_directory->getAbsolutePath($tmpPath)
            );
            $destinationRealPath = $this->_directory->getDriver()->getRealPath($destPath);
            $relativeDestPath = $this->_directory->getRelativePath($destPath);
            $isSameFile = $tmpRealPath === $destinationRealPath;
            $rootDirectory = $this->getTargetDirectory()->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT);
            return $isSameFile ?: $this->_directory->copyFile($tmpPath, $relativeDestPath, $rootDirectory);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Append temp path to filename
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @return string
     */
    private function getTempFilePath(string $filename): string
    {
        return $this->getTmpDir()
            ? rtrim($this->getTmpDir(), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename
            : $filename;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function chmod($file)
    {
        //phpcs:ignore Squiz.PHP.NonExecutableCode.ReturnNotRequired
        return;
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves target directory.
     *
     * @return TargetDirectory
     */
    private function getTargetDirectory(): TargetDirectory
    {
        if (!isset($this->targetDirectory)) {
            $this->targetDirectory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(TargetDirectory::class);
        }

        return $this->targetDirectory;
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

Here is my registration.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'CustomVendor_UploaderOverride', __DIR__);
```

UPDATE:

It looks like the only way I can get this to work if I directly change the plugins that extend the Magento Uploader class to the CustomVendor plugin.

Do the preference overrides not work when other classes directly mention Magento Uploader class?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is validate your module is enabled:

```
php bin/magento mod:sta
```

and verify your module appears correctly

If it does not appear, I suggest to verify you have a file registration.php in your module?

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CustomVendor_UploaderOverride',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Yeah the plugin is enabled. I wonder if something else is using a preference for that class and thats why the preference is not working. Is there a way to look this up without doing a grep through the whole /vendor folder?